# how to detect tomcat session expiration using spring

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-security

i am running wicket with spring and use spring security , when tomcat session , the one which declared in the web.xml expired

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I want to catch this event using a filter(not overiding existing httpSession or Session ) 
how can I achive that using spring ?

10x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a listener class to achieve this. Define a listener component as below:

```
@Component
public class AppLogoutListener implements
        ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> {


    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event) {
        // from event you can obtain SecurityContexts to work with


    }

}
```

You need to define a session event publisher in your web.xml:

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Here the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` publishes the session life cycle events whenever sessions are created and expired.

Comment: This will add a dependency on Spring Security (which doesn't have to be a problem if you already have that). You can also implement a `HttpSessionListener` yourself and imlpement the `sessionDestroyed` method. Whatever method you choose it will also be called when a user does a logout of your application (there is no way to distinguise between an expiry and the calling of `session.invalidate` by code.