# HttpSession setMaxInactiveInterval do not trigger Spring Security session SessionDestroyedEvent

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-security, httpsession, spring-session

I have a listener to set session timeout dynamically

```
public class DynamicSessionTimeoutHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener{

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        long sessionTimeoutInMinute = ConfigEntryMgr.getInstance().getByKeyAsLong(ConfigEntryKeys.SESSION_TIMEOUT_IN_MINUTE);
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval((int) sessionTimeoutInMinute * 60);

    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {

    }
```

}

In spring security I do not allow concurrent session:

```
<beans:bean id="sas"
class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
                <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
                <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
            </beans:bean>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy">
            </beans:bean>
            <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

As a result nobody can login with a username that already is logged in.

The problem is that setMaxInactiveInterval does not destroy spring session.

Unless first user open the browser again and do an action, the servlet does not find out this session has expired to trigger SessionDestroyedEvent.

Now if the first user just close his browser, no body can login with this user forever, because Spring Security thinks somebody is still logged in with this username

Comment: Seems similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589220/how-to-detect-tomcat-session-expiration-using-spring

Comment: Nope, Session-Timeout does not behave like setMaxInactiveInterval, Session-Timeout trigger SessionDestroyedEvent but setMaxInactiveInterval only set a restriction on session and wait for user to send some request with that session, then destroy it.

Comment: Apache Tomcat, for example, may have a background thread configured that expires sessions, and that thread calls [processExpires](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/session/ManagerBase.java#L564) and ends up calling the [listeners](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardSession.java#L801)

Comment: Yes Apache Tomcat handle it somehow, I know that, I'm asking how to handle it without set timeout in web.xml and user setMaxInactiveInterval instead

Comment: works the same way, regardless of how you set the timeout (code or xml). did you configure the Spring http listener, so that Spring is informed of the event? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589220/how-to-detect-tomcat-session-expiration-using-spring)

Simplest thing you can do, is create your own listener, and see if gets invoked.